# Vue3: Displaying of nested JSON object data does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

i am trying to display data from a nested JSON object. The data is retrieved correctly from axios but I dont get it to be displayed.

The json object looks like this:

```json
{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Germany",
        "continent": "Europe",
        "president": {
            "id": "12",
            "name": "Joanna Doe",
        }
}
```

In the vue component the data is saved in the "country" object.

```js
. . .
data() {
   country: {},
}
```

If I then try to render it in vue template, I get all the data if I render following:

```html
<p>{{ country }}</p>
```

But if I do try to render the data of the nested "president" attribute like this:

```html
<p>{{ country.president.name }} </p>
```

I get following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (CountryDetail.vue:25)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1165)
    at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5184)
    at reactiveEffect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:42)
    at effect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:17)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5137)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5096)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5054)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4660)
    at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5191)
```

Is there anyway how to render this nested data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`country` is initially an empty object (and later updated), but your template tries to render the nested properties immediately in:

```html
<p>{{ country.president.name }} </p>
```

That results in an error because `country.president` initially does not exist, so it's `undefined`, leading to the error of reading `name` from `undefined`.

One way to solve this is to [conditionally render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) that `<p>` only when `country.president` is defined:

```html
<p v-if="country.president">{{ country.president.name }}</p>
```

Alternatively with Vue 3, you could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid the runtime error. However, the `<p>` element would still be rendered with an empty body. (If the empty tag is undesired, stick with the conditional rendering solution above.)

```html
<p>{{ country.president?.name }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma `,` after `"continent": "Europe"` <- right here.

Your code should work. [See this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCB7IHJlZiB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZSdcbmNvbnN0IGNvdW50cnkgPSByZWYoe1xuICBcImlkXCI6IFwiMVwiLFxuICBcIm5hbWVcIjogXCJHZXJtYW55XCIsXG4gIFwiY29udGluZW50XCI6IFwiRXVyb3BlXCIsXG4gIFwicHJlc2lkZW50XCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImlkXCI6IFwiMTJcIixcbiAgICBcIm5hbWVcIjogXCJKb2FubmEgRG9lXCIsXG4gIH1cbn0pXG48L3NjcmlwdD5cblxuPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuPHA+e3sgY291bnRyeS5wcmVzaWRlbnQubmFtZSB9fTwvcD5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+IiwiaW1wb3J0LW1hcC5qc29uIjoie1xuICBcImltcG9ydHNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwidnVlXCI6IFwiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZmMudnVlanMub3JnL3Z1ZS5ydW50aW1lLmVzbS1icm93c2VyLmpzXCJcbiAgfVxufSJ9)

Comment: I think that's a typo only in the question. Otherwise, the OP would get a `SyntaxError` before even seeing the `TypeError`.